# Using Ajax to upload file in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Well..I'm new to codeigniter. And I'm stuck on this problem from days!
I read many questions and answers telling about file upload using ajax. But I can't find a specific solution to my problem.
There is the View :

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/upload_cover', array("id" => "upload_file"));?>
<input type="file" id="coverpic" name="userfile" size="20" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right"/>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Controller : Upload, method upload_cover

```
public function upload_cover() {
$file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
$userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
$ext = end(explode('.', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));
$_FILES['userfile']['name'] = "$userid.$ext";
$config['upload_path'] = './img/cover/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '200000';
$config['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['max_height']  = '768';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if ( !$this->upload->do_upload())
  {
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $data['body'] = 'body_profile';
    $data['error'] = $error;
    $this->load->view('include/template_profile', $data);
  }
  else {
    $cover = "$userid.$ext";
    echo $cover;
    $this->load->model('dbconnect');
    $this->dbconnect->editCover($userid, $cover);
    //$this->index();
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $image_path = $data['full_path'];
    if(file_exists($image_path))
    {
      echo json_encode($image_path);
    }
    //redirect('homepage/');
    //echo base_url()."img/cover/".
  }
```

Now my problem is... This code is working without ajax... I want to write this using Ajax, so that image is uploaded and shown in its div on clicking Upload button.

So what should I pass in data of ajax request to use the above controller method itself?
Thank you..

Comment: This link http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax will tell you how to upload files using ajax. You can figure out how to combine this with CodeIgniter yourself.

Comment: Thank you Meneer, I tried the link and was able to upload file. But its not ajax. The file upload happens on submit only i.e. on refresh of the page. But this was the start I was looking for! Thank you.. shared the ajax solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well.. you need jquery.form this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var $form = $('#myform');
    var $btn = $('#submit'); // upload button

    $btn.click(function() {
        // implement with ajaxForm Plugin
        $form.ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function() {
                // xyz
            },
            success: function(img_url) {
                $form.resetForm();
                alert(img_url);
                //$myimage.attr('src', img_url);
            },
            error: function(error_msg) {
                  alert('error:' + error_msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

also you need return (or stored in json) an url from php :)

Comment: Thank you.. I have used form like your method. It works. Now my problem is, I'm saving new image with the same name as the previous one. Or is there a way to unlink my previously saved image? Can you help me with that? I will update my solution next.

Comment: Hi, You can use uniqid() for new file name, or the upload tmp name: $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); $upload_data['full_path']

Answer (score 0):

View :

```
<div class="upload" id="upload" style="display:none">
    <form id="form-id" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <input type="file" id="coverpic" name="userfile" size="20" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right"/>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

Controller : Upload, method upload_cover

```
public function upload_cover() {
$userid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
$config['upload_path'] = 'C:\wamp\www\Twitter_Project\img\cover';
$config['upload_url'] = base_url().'files/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['max_size'] = '1000KB';
$config['max_width'] = '4096';
$config['max_height'] = '2160';
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
$config['file_name'] = $userid;
$this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
  {
      //$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

      //$this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
      echo "error";
  }
  else
  {
    //$username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $ext = end(explode('.', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));
    $data = "$userid.$ext";
    //$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
    $this->load->model('dbconnect');
    $this->dbconnect->editCover($userid, $data);

      //$this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
      echo json_encode($data);
  }
  @unlink($_FILES['userfile']);
  echo 'unlinked user file';
}
```

Ajax method :

```
$('#form-id').on('submit', function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
$.ajax({
url: base + 'upload/upload_cover',
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',
data: data,
processData: false,
contentType: false,
cache: false
}).done(function(data) {
  if(data !== 'error'){
    console.log("success");
    console.log(data);
    var path = base + 'img/cover/' + data;
    console.log(path);
    console.log( $('#sp1')[0].src);
    //$('#sp1')[0].src = path;
    $('#sp1').attr('src',path);
  }
  else{
    alert("Cannot upload your cover picture. Please try again.");
  }
})
});
```

This is a working solution, one will have to write only the model method separately.
Now, I dont want to get the previously saved image name to unlink so here I overwrite the image. Is there a way to overwrite the cached image other than changing filename?

Comment: Done that too. Silly thing. Save by timestamp and unlink previous file. :P